# TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array when training Yolo model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection, yolo

I followed the famous Yolo open source example (link shown below) and one class images and annotation files on Colab and tried to train a Yolo object detection model. However, there is an error below after starting to run the train function at the beginning. Can anyone help to indicate the directions how to fix the error or the directions how to debug this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Reference source code, I only do very minor modifications on the code:
https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/master/examples/Blood%20Cell%20Detection.ipynb

Last line of code:

```
model.fit(train_batch, steps_per_epoch  = len(train_batch), \
                epochs           = 100, \
                verbose          = 1,\
                validation_data  = valid_batch,\
                validation_steps = len(valid_batch),\
                callbacks        = [early_stop, checkpoint, tensorboard], \
                max_queue_size   = 3)
```

```
Epoch 1/100

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-28-184363817955> in <module>()
         15 model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=optimizer)
         16 
    ---> 17 model.fit(train_batch,                     steps_per_epoch  = len(train_batch),                     
    epochs           = 100,                     verbose          = 1,                    
    validation_data  = valid_batch,                    validation_steps = len(valid_batch),                    
    callbacks        = [early_stop, checkpoint, tensorboard],                     max_queue_size   = 3)

    9 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, 
    y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
       1098                 _r=1):
       1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
    -> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
       1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
       1102                 context.async_wait()

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
        826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
        827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
    --> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
        829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
        830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
        869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
        870       initializers = []
    --> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
        872     finally:
        873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
        724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
        725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    --> 726             *args, **kwds))
        727 
        728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2967       args, kwargs = None, None
       2968     with self._lock:
    -> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
       2970     return graph_function
       2971 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
       3359 
       3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
    -> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
       3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
       3363 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
       3204             arg_names=arg_names,
       3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
    -> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
       3207         self._function_attributes,
       3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
        988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
        989 
    --> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
        991 
        992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
        632             xla_context.Exit()
        633         else:
    --> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
        635         return out
        636 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
       975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
       976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
    --> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
        978             else:
        979               raise

    TypeError: in user code:

        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
            return step_function(self, iterator)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
            outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
            return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
            return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
            outputs = model.train_step(data)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756 train_step
            y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:238 __call__
            total_loss_metric_value, sample_weight=batch_dim)
         /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
            update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
            return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:364 update_state  **
    sample_weight, values)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/weights_broadcast_ops.py:155 broadcast_weights
            values = ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name="values")
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:163 wrapped
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1540 convert_to_tensor
            ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:339 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
            return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:265 constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:283 _constant_impl
            allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:435 make_tensor_proto
            values = np.asarray(values)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:83 asarray
             return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py:274 __array__
            'Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. '

         TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. 

         This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a
```

lambda layer in the Functional Model.

Comment: What are the tensorflow and numpy versions you are using?

Comment: Tensorflow: 2.4.1
Python: 3.7.10 
Numpy: 1.19.5

Comment: If you are using keras make sure you are adding `from tensorflow import keras`. Try upgrading the numpy to latest version.

Comment: Thanks. However, 'from tensorflow import keras' has been on the code already. I am using Colab so suppose the working environment should not be a problem?

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47311#issuecomment-826400220) workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Tried, did not help